# Why the variable doc return null all the time?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im downloading images from a website.
This is the code:

```
class MyClient : WebClient
        {
            public bool HeadOnly { get; set; }
            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
            {
                WebRequest req = base.GetWebRequest(address);
                if (HeadOnly && req.Method == "GET")
                {
                    req.Method = "HEAD";
                }
                return req;
            }
        }
```

Then the method:

```
public static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument getHtmlDocumentWebClient(string url, bool useProxy, string proxyIp, int proxyPort, string usename, string password)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = null;
            try
            {
                doc = null;
                using (MyClient clients = new MyClient())
                {
                    clients.HeadOnly = true;
                    byte[] body = clients.DownloadData(url);
                    // note should be 0-length
                    string type = clients.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
                    clients.HeadOnly = false;
                    // check 'tis not binary... we'll use text/, but could
                    // check for text/html
                    if (type == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (type.StartsWith(@"text/html"))
                        {
                            string text = clients.DownloadString(url);

                            try
                            {
                                doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                                //client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                                client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
                                if (useProxy)
                                {
                                    //Proxy                
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyIp))
                                    {
                                        WebProxy p = new WebProxy(proxyIp, proxyPort);
                                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usename))
                                        {
                                            if (password == null)
                                                password = string.Empty;
                                            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(usename, password);
                                            p.Credentials = nc;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                doc.Load(client.OpenRead(url));
                            }
                            catch
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (doc == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Doc is null   " + doc + " The link that did it was    " + url);
                }

            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return doc;
        }
```

I tried to add general try catch to the method but it still getting to the MessageBox and not to the catch.

Anyway the link of the image im trying to download is:

http://members.tripod.com/~DannyWest/bundy.jpg

Then i used a breakpoin t and on the line:

```
if (type.StartsWith(@"text/html"))
```

Its jumping to the MessageBox.Show...

Now i saw that type contain: image/jpeg
I wonder if is that the problem since there is not text/html or something else maybe something with the link ?

EDIT**

I tried to change the method added this:

```
if (type.StartsWith(@"text/html")|| type.StartsWith(@"image/jpeg"))
```

Added the part image/jpeg
But then its getting to this method on another class:

```
private List<string> getLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
        {

                List<string> mainLinks = new List<string>();
                var linkNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
                if (linkNodes != null)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode link in linkNodes)
                    {
                        var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                        if (href.StartsWith("http://") == true || href.StartsWith("https://") == true || href.StartsWith("www") == true) // filter for http 
                        {
                            mainLinks.Add(href);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return mainLinks;


        }
```

And linkNodes is null all the time.
When the type.StartsWith is image/jpeg then this linkNodes allways null.
When type.StartsWith is text/html then linkNodes is not null.

I can upload my project to my skydrive if needed.

Comment: the image link you gave goes to 404...

Comment: Here is a working link: http://www.members.tripod.com/~VanessaWest/Joe_-_brother.jpg

Comment: Now i tried another site and the images downloaded good but the variable type this time contain: text/html; charset=utf-8 so i wonder why here the type is text/html; charset=utf-8 and its downloading the images and in the other link the type variable contain image/jpeg and not text/html; charset=utf-8 ?

Comment: @DanielVest what image has the text/html???

Comment: No. The value of type.StartsWith is now image/jpeg

Comment: When type.StartsWith contain text/html from a link its downloading images. But if type.StartsWith contain image/jpeg it dosent download the images doc is null in this method and linkNodes is null too. A link that is working and downloading images www.walla.co.il and a link that dosent download the image from there fro example: http://members.tripod.com/~VanessaWest/bundybowman3.jpg for some reason it cant download this image.

Comment: Remove (comment out) all catch blocks; run your program in a debugger.

Comment: Why are you trying to process an *image* URL (it's a `.jpg`) with HAP? That can only handle html source code. What happens if you point your code to a url of a real page? If you have a good reason to use HPA on a .jpg-URL, please explain.

Comment: Why are you using all these `try` blocks? You're catching potentially useful exceptions to do literally nothing.

Comment: I dont have any reason to use process an image URL. And i will remove this try catch blocks. This methos that make the doc variable null is part of my project that is a webcrawler.

Comment: Here is my complete project maybe someone can download and try it and see the problem more clear ? https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!296&authkey=!AKXqSn0Zzvjm72w